# What kind of bugs do "goto" statements lead to? Are there any historically significant examples?

Tags: coding-style, history, bug, bad-code, goto

I understand that save for breaking out of loops nested in loops; the `goto` statement is evaded and reviled as a bug prone style of programming, to never be used.

[image: XKCD]
<sup>**Alt Text:** *"Neal Stephenson thinks it's cute to name his labels 'dengo' "* 
 **See the original comic at: http://xkcd.com/292/**</sup>

Because I learned this early; I don't really have any insight or experience on what types of bugs `goto` actually leads to. So what are we talking about here:

- Instability?
- Unmaintainable or unreadable code?
- Security vulnerabilities?
- Something else entirely?

What kind of bugs do "goto" statements actually lead to? Are there any historically significant examples?

Comment: It's worth noting that gotos are used quite a lot in the Linux kernel. My OS professor in grad school was (is) very much in favor of these for their simplicity. I'm hardly advocating using gotos everywhere, just pointing it out because your original post implies you've learned it as "bad" regardless of context. Slightly more here: [Why do some kernel programmers use goto instead of simple while loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13001067)

Comment: Have you read Dijkstra's original short paper on this topic?  (That is a Yes/No question, and any answer other than an unequivocal instant "yes" is a "no".)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I read it as per your recommendation. There was some things I had difficulty understanding. For example: What are alarm exits, and why does he want to restrict the use to only that designation?

Comment: Have you ever seen code using `while(true)` or `while(1)`? The main problem with `goto` is the same. IT breaks the entire stucture/logic **and** readability of the code in exchange for some one-time comfort.

Comment: I presume an alarm exit is when something catastrophic failure happens. where you will never return from. Like power failure, disappearing devices or files.

Some kinds of "on error goto"...

But I think most "almost catastropic" errors can be handled by "try - catch" constructs nowadays.

Comment: Have you ever refactored a program written in assembly language, old line-numbered BASIC, or similar language that lacks higher-level control-flow statements than `GOTO`, `IF`...`GOTO`, or `GOSUB`?

Comment: For an example of what dan is talking about, take a look at [this maze generator program](https://archive.org/stream/More_BASIC_Computer_Games_1980_Creative_Computing#page/n117/mode/2up) (might have to download the PDF for the text to be readable).  The BASIC program presented only uses simple commands, but how easy is it to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Nobody's mentioned the calculated GOTO yet.  Back when the earth was young BASIC had line numbers.  You could write the following:  100 N = A*100; GOTO N. Try debugging that :)

Comment: @mcottle: in dialects of BASIC (e.g., Atari BASIC) that supported arbitrary numeric expressions as `GOTO` targets like that, it was a useful shortcut for emulating `switch` statements.

Comment: @dan04 yep, that's what I used them for.  It was either that or an endless list of if thens doing the same jumps at the end.  We lived in fear of the time we called "The great renumbering" :)

Comment: I kind of think this is a red herring to get us to repeat the reasons goto is generally banned in software engineering (and apparently get us to list the exceptions as well).

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I have read Dijkstra's paper.  It was written in 1968 and suggests that the need for gotos might be reduced in languages that include such advanced features as switch statements and functions.  It was written in response to languages in which goto was the primary method of flow control, and could be used to jump to any point in the program.  Whereas in languages that were developed after this paper was written, e.g. C, goto can only jump to places in the same stack frame, and is generally used only when other options don't work well.  (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) His points were valid at the time, but are no longer relevant, *regardless* of whether goto is a good idea or not.  If we want to argue that one way or another, arguments must be made that relate to modern languages.  By the way, have *you* read Knuth's "Structured Programming with goto Statements"?

Comment: I think the picture is giving the wrong idea. If you still use goto then you are the dinosaur among programmers. ;) Or into esoteric programming languages.

Comment: @Ray: Yes, I have read Knuth's "Structured Programming With goto Statements".  I disagree strongly with it.

Comment: Dijkstra's points in his original paper may be reconstructed as "programmers are human, and some humans are unable to resist the temptation of the goto statement to make a mess of their program".  "Don't make a mess of it" runs all through Dijkstra's writings and philosophy.

Comment: GOTO is a fantastic color with which to paint the bike shed :-)  "...we've really been directing our attention to the wrong issue, to the objective question of go to elimination instead of the important subjective question of program structure." - Knuth

Comment: @mg30rg What is the problem with `while(1)`, especially for a program's main loop (assuming the program is something like a daemon or a GUI that is meant to run indefinitely)?

Comment: @Lenne That assumes that you're using a language that supports exceptions and that you actually like exceptions.

Comment: @KyleStrand For starters, the problem is that it is a lie. No piece of code or program is meant to be run forever. The right way to write a main loop is to write `while (!terminated)`. The other problem is abuse. If you write logical code, you can see the exact conditions leading to leave a while loop only by reading its header. If you use `while(1)` you obviously will have one- or more hidden `break`s or `continue`s _somewhere_ inside your loop. A `break` is just like a `goto`; it is a "quick and dirty" solution destroying consistency.

Comment: Anecdotally, In my first programming job, I was taught the avoidance of spaghetti code. In a code base I currently maintain, there are many examples of this constructed with dozens of goto statements. The only way to maintain this code (or even to understand it with the intent to rewrite) is to print it out, then sit for hours with the paper spread over a large conference table and draw lines from each goto to each destination. Consequently I am of the firm opinion that goto is a blight that should have been strangled at birth and expunged from human memory and all records of it erased.

Comment: GOTO is a tool. In the hands of a skilled programmer, it'll be well used. That being said, there are often better tools than GOTO available in modern languages, but why would you consider a tool to be a bad one, if it's designed to do one and only one thing?

Comment: @mg30rg I've seen that argument before (I thought it was in a comments discussion on this site, actually, but I can't find it), and as presented I just don't yet find it convincing. Care to discuss in chat, and/or to provide a link to a more full explanation (preferably from a known programming expert)?

Comment: @mcottle - To add to the fun COBOL had altered GOTO statements (so you could change the label that an apparent label referred to), and PL/1 had label variables (so you could do a goto to a label which you could assign to at any point, or could be an array of label variables so you could do a goto to an element of that array). To me routines should have a single exit point, and doing a return from half way through a routine is just as lazy and poorly readable as a GOTO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse That gave me flashbacks to learning to program on a C128 & GWBasic & TurboBasic.

Comment: `goto` is a sign of a weakness in the programmer, or in the language. `goto` is a shallow abstraction of the assembler instruction `jmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to look at it I have not seen in the other answers yet.

It is about scope. One of the main pillars of good programming practice is keeping your scope tight. You need tight scope because you lack the mental ability to oversee and understand more than just a few logical steps. So you create small blocks (each of which becomes "one thing") and then build with those to create bigger blocks which become one thing, and so on. This keeps things manageable and comprehensible.

A goto effectively inflates the scope of your logic to the entire program. This is sure to defeat your brain for any but the smallest programs spanning only a few lines.

So you will not be able to tell if you made a mistake anymore because there is just too much to take in and check for your poor little head. This is the real problem, bugs are just a likely result.

Comment: Non-local goto?

Comment: https://thebrain.mcgill.ca/flash/capsules/experience_jaune03.html << The human mind can keep track of an average of 7 things at once. Your rationale plays into this limitation, as expanding scope will add many more things which need to be kept track of. Thus the types of bugs that will be introduced are likely one's of omission and forgetfulness. You also offer a mitigating strategy and good practice in general, of "keeping your scope tight". As such, I accept this answer. Good Job Martin.

Comment: How cool is that?! Among over 200 votes casted, winning with just 1!

Answer (score 69):

It isn't that the `goto` is bad by itself.
(After all, every jump instruction in a computer is a goto.)
The problem is that there is a human style of programming that pre-dates structured programming, what could be called "flow-chart" programming.

In flow-chart programming (which people of my generation learned, and was used for the Apollo moon program) you make a diagram with blocks for statement executions and diamonds for decisions, and you could connect them with lines that go all over the place. (So-called "spaghetti code".)

The problem with spaghetti code is that you, the programmer, could "know" it was right, but how could you *prove* it, to yourself or anybody else?
In fact, it might actually have a potential misbehavior, and your knowledge that it is always correct could be wrong.

Along came *structured programming* with begin-end blocks, for, while, if-else, and so on.
These had the advantage that you could still do anything in them, but if you were at all careful, you could be sure your code was correct.

Of course, people can still write spaghetti code even without `goto`. The common method is to write a `while(...) switch( iState ){...`, where different cases set the `iState` to different values. In fact, in C or C++ one could write a macro to do that, and name it `GOTO`, so saying you're not using `goto` is a distinction without a difference.

As an example of how code-proving can preclude unrestricted `goto`, a long time ago I stumbled on a control structure useful for dynamically-changing user interfaces.
I called it [*differential execution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875909/23771).
It is fully Turing-universal, but its correctness proof depends on pure structured programming - no `goto`, `return`, `continue`, `break`, or exceptions.

[image]

Comment: Correctness cannot be *proven* except in the most trivial of programs, even when structured programming is used to write them.  You can only increase your level of confidence; structured programming does accomplish that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Of course. I'm just thinking of Dijkstra, who claimed to have written a whole OS proven correct. At the same time, I played for years with automatically proving correctness of simple bubble sort, and it was a real chore.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Related: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."
https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/p.vanemdeboas/knuthnote.pdf

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's [not quite true](http://compcert.inria.fr/) that correctness proofs are only practical for trivial programs. More specialized tools than structured programming are necessary, however.

Comment: @MikeHaskel: It's tell-tale that they implement a C90 compiler, not C99 or C11. They seem to have a challenge in keeping up with the evolution of C (!!)

Comment: @MSalters: It's a research project. The goal of such a research project is to show that they *could* write a verified compiler if they had the resources. If you look at their current work, you will see that they are simply not interested in supporting later versions of C, rather they are interested in expanding the correctness properties they can prove. And for that, it is simply completely irrelevant whether they support C90, C99, C11, Pascal, Fortran, Algol, or Plankalkül.

Comment: @MSalters it also takes quite a few PhDs of work to get anywhere. If you started again every time a new version came out, there would be little progress. Furthermore, far more real code exists for C90 than for C11, so it's much more useful to concentrate on the older standard.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I'd disagree with that statement; proving the correctness of VLA usage is non-trivial. Designated initializers OTOH are bookkeeping.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've seen a proof of a primitive dynamic system. It was so long, complicated and error-prone that you were much more likely to make a mistake in the proof, rather than the program. And for a typical procedural program with lots of mutable state, you can't really compose the proofs to build complex programs from simple proven elements. Changing the way we program is the only way to practical proofs about programs - we need to limit the problem space a lot. Meanwhile, in the real world, bad state recovery seems to be a lot more successful than proving correctness so far...

Comment: @Luaan: This is a very interesting discussion. I've changed my viewpoint to a different one, namely that domain-specific-languages (DSLs) need to be taken a whole lot more seriously. I.e. consider the mental task of programming as a Shannon-type information channel, and keeps its redundancy down to a minimum, so as to minimize the opportunity for noise (bugs). The DSL takes on the role of the target alphabet. You prove the DSL implementation, not the user program. It does require accepting the cost of the learning curve of the DSL.

Comment: @martineau: I'm leery of those "boson phrases", where programmers sort of fall in line agreeing that it's bad or good, because they'll get sat on if they don't. There have to be more basic reasons for things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Re:"Correctness cannot be proven except in the most trivial of programs" - I am reminded of the "Hello World with a pause" program that a professor assigned in my Intro to Computer Science class in college. I think there were around 75 people and not a single person was able to write even a trivial program like that without the professor being able to crash it. That has always stuck with me. Thus, I think your statement should have ended with ""Correctness cannot be proven".

Comment: behold [the friendship algoithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0xgjUhEG3U) . Or just the [image here](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/File:The_Friendship_Algorithm.jpg)

Comment: The diagram you show is a reasonably well structured algorithm. It is emphatically not spaghetti code! (It's a loop with one break criteria and a couple of optional processing steps each guarded by conditions. There is no jumping into the loop, there is just a nice single loop exit, the whole diagram -- a subroutine? -- has a single entry and exit and thus is properly loosely coupled to callers.) Yes, one *could* draw all kinds of arrows in it, but they aren't there. It would, for example, translate nicely into a Nassi-Shneiderman diagram which was invented to prevent the arbitrary arrows.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: You're right. I didn't claim it was spaghetti code, just a flow chart. Anyway, bolov's suggestion of the [*friendship algorithm*](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/File:The_Friendship_Algorithm.jpg) is a better choice, so I replaced the image.

Comment: I hesitate to jump into the fray here but it's pretty obvious to me that verifiability is not relevant at the level of a non-trivial application.  Isn't the major importance of verifiability that it allows for more and better optimizations?

Comment: @Jimmy: Welcome to the fray! I agree with your first sentence. I also agree with the second except that 1) if you write compilers, you must do good optimizations, because the few users who need them *really* need them, and 2) most users who write applications think they need optimizations, but they don't :)

Comment: *The common method is to write a while(...) switch( iState ){..., where different cases set the iState to different values.* Holy crap. O_O

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I may have not been clear here but I was only referring to  compiler optimizations such as what happens in a JIT optimizer.  If the code isn't verfiable, I believe this limits the kinds of things that can be done.  For example, if you use gotos to jump in and out of loops conditionally, I think it would be hard/impossible to unroll such loops using a generalized approach.  I'm confused by the last of your response because most common high-level languages and VMs optimize whether the developer is aware of it or not.

Comment: @Jimmy: That's OK, maybe the point is a bit nuanced. As I said, I agree that compiler optimizations require verifiability, and those optimizations are absolutely necessary. OTOH, Joe and Nancy coders write lots of mega-line apps where system or library calls are almost always low down in the call stack. The compiler optimizes their code anyway, even though the benefit is nearly zero because the IP is seldom in it. At the same time, they seldom consider the kinds of optimizations [*only coders can do*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I get what you are saying but I also think people would be surprised how much slower their code would run if so much of what they put into it wasn't stripped out by various optimizers.  Most of the time the performance problems that don't benefit from optimitzation I see are a result of creating large data structures in memory for no good reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey structured programming is necessary but not sufficient to prove a program.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I never implied otherwise, though I fundamentally disagree with your statement.  There's nothing about structured programming that is particularly relevant to proofs, and since non-trivial programs cannot be proven, whether it is necessary or not is immaterial.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you miss-understand me well. I would try to explain, but this has never worked in the past, to I will not attempt now. I will just go on writing bug-free software. I know you don't believe me, no one does, except my boss, and some of the people that I work with.

Answer (score 67):

### Why is goto dangerous?

- `goto` doesn't cause instability by itself. Despite [about 100,000 `goto`s, the Linux kernel](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/894) is still a model of stability.
- `goto` by itself should not cause security vulnerabilities. In some languages however, mixing it with `try`/`catch` exception management blocks could lead to vulnerabilities as explained in this [CERT recommendation](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/VOID+Do+not+use+goto+statement+to+take+control+inside+the+try+and+catch+blocks). Mainstream C++ compilers flag and prevent such errors, but unfortunately, older or more exotic compilers don't.
- `goto` causes unreadable and unmaintainable code. This is also called [*spaghetti code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), because, like in a spaghetti plate, it's very difficult to follow the flow of control when there are too many gotos.

Even if you manage to avoid spaghetti code and if you use only a few gotos, they still facilitate bugs like and resource leaking:

- Code using structure programming, with clear nested blocks and loops or switches, is easy to follow; its flow of control is very predictable. It's therefore easier to ensure that invariants are respected.
- With a `goto` statement, you break that straightforward flow, and break the expectations. For example, you might not notice that you have still to free resources.
- Many `goto` in different places can send you to a single goto target. So it's not obvious to know for sure the state you are in when reaching this place. The risk of making wrong/unfounded assumptions is hence quite big.

### Additional information and quotes:

- [E.Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) wrote an early essay about the topic already in 1968: "*[Go To Statement Considered Harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful)*"
- [Brian.W.Kernighan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) & [Dennis.M.Ritchie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) wrote in the C programming language:

> C provides the infinitely-abusable `goto` statement and labels to
>   branch to. Formally the `goto` is never necessary, and in practice it
>   is almost always easy to write code without it. (...) 
>   Nonetheless we will suggest a few situations
>   where goto 's may find a place. The most common use is to abandon
>   processing in some deeply nested structures, such as breaking out of
>   two loops at once. (...)
>   Although we are not dogmatic about the matter, it does seem that **goto statements should be used sparingly, if at all**.

- [James Gosling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling) & Henry McGilton wrote in their [1995 Java language environment white paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/1995_Java_whitepaper.pdf):

  > **No More Goto Statements** 
  > Java has no goto statement. Studies illustrated that goto is (mis)used more often than not simply “because
  >   it’s there”. Eliminating goto led to a simplification of the language
  >   (...) Studies on approximately 100,000 lines of C code determined that
  >   roughly 90 percent of the goto statements were used purely to obtain
  >   the effect of breaking out of nested loops. As mentioned above,
  >   multi-level break and continue remove most of the need for goto
  >   statements.
- [Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/) defines goto in his [glossary](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html) in these inviting terms:

  > goto - the infamous goto. Primarily useful in machine generated C++ code.

### When could goto be used?

Like K&R I'm not dogmatic about gotos. I admit that there are situations where goto could be ease one's life.

Typically, in C, goto allows multilevel loop exit, or error handling requiring to reach an appropriate exit point that frees/unlocks all the resources that were allocated so far (i.e.multiple allocation in sequence means multiple labels).  [This article](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/894) quantifies the different uses of the goto in the Linux kernel.

Personally I prefer to avoid it and in 10 years of C, I used maximum 10 gotos. I prefer to use nested `if`s, which I think are more readable. When this would lead to a too deep nesting, I'd opt either to decompose my function in smaller parts, or use an boolean indicator in cascade. Today's optimizing compilers are clever enough to generate almost the same code than the same code with `goto`.

The use of goto heavily depends on the language:

- In C++, proper use of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) causes the compiler to automatically destroy objects that go out of scope, so that the resources/lock will be cleaned anyway, and no real need for goto any more.
- In Java there's no need for goto (see Java's author quote above and this [excellent Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547764/3723423)): the garbage collector that cleans the mess, `break`,`continue`, and `try`/`catch` exception handling cover all the case where `goto` could be helpful, but in a safer and better manner. Java's popularity proves that goto statement can be avoided in a modern language.

### Zoom on the famous *SSL goto fail* vulnerability

***Important Disclaimer:*** in view of the fierce discussion in the comments, I want to clarify that I don't pretend that the goto statement is the only cause of this bug. I don't pretend that without goto there would be no bug. I just want to show that a goto can be involved in a serious bug.

I don't know how many serious bugs are related to `goto` in the history of programming: details are often not communicated. However there was a famous [Apple SSL bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) that weakened the security of iOS. The statement that led to this bug was a wrong `goto` statement.

Some argue that the root cause of the bug was not the goto statement in itself, but a wrong copy/paste, a misleading indentation, missing curly braces around the conditional block, or perhaps the working habits of the developer. I can't neither confirm any of them: all these arguments are probable hypotheses and interpretation. Nobody really knows. (*meanwhile, the hypothesis of a merge that went wrong as someone suggested in the comments seems to be a very good candidate in view of some other indentation inconsistencies in the same function*).

The only objective fact is that a duplicated  `goto` led to exit the function prematurely. Looking at the code, the only other single statement that could have caused the same effect would have been a return.

The error is in function `SSLEncodeSignedServerKeyExchange()` in [this file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_ssl/lib/sslKeyExchange.c):

```c
    if ((err = ReadyHash(&SSLHashSHA1, &hashCtx)) != 0)
        goto fail;
    if ((err =...) !=0)
        goto fail;
    if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
        goto fail;
        goto fail;  // <====OUCH: INDENTATION MISLEADS: THIS IS UNCONDITIONDAL!!
    if (...)
        goto fail;

    ... // Do some cryptographic operations here

fail:
    ... // Free resources to process error
```

Indeed curly braces around the conditional block could have prevented the bug: 
 it would have led either to a syntax error at compilation (and hence a correction) or to a redundant harmless goto. By the way, GCC 6 would be able to spot these errors thanks to its optional warning to detect inconsistent indentation.

But in first place, all these gotos could have been avoided with more structured code. So goto is at least indirectly a cause of this bug. There are at least two different ways that could have avoided it:

***Approach 1: if clause or nested `if`s***

Instead of testing lots of conditions for error sequentially, and each time sending to a `fail` label in case of problem, one could have opted for executing the cryptographic operations in an `if`-statement that would do it only if there was no wrong pre-condition:

```c
    if ((err = ReadyHash(&SSLHashSHA1, &hashCtx)) == 0 &&
        (err = ...) == 0 ) &&
        (err = ReadyHash(&SSLHashSHA1, &hashCtx)) == 0) &&
        ...
        (err = ...) == 0 ) )
    {
         ... // Do some cryptographic operations here
    }
    ... // Free resources
```

**Approach 2: use an error accumulator**

This approach is based on the fact that almost all the statements here call some function to set an `err` error code, and execute the rest of the code only if `err` was 0 (i.e., function executed without error). A nice safe and readable alternative is:

```c
bool ok = true;
ok =  ok && (err = ReadyHash(&SSLHashSHA1, &hashCtx))) == 0;
ok =  ok && (err = NextFunction(...)) == 0;
...
ok =  ok && (err = ...) == 0;
... // Free resources
```

Here, there is not a single goto: no risk to jump to quickly to the failure exit point. And visually it would be easy to spot a misaligned line or a forgotten `ok &&`.

This construct is more compact. It is based on the fact that in C, the second part of a logical and (`&&`) is evaluated only if the first part is true. In fact, the assembler generated by an optimizing compiler is almost equivalent to the original code with gotos: The optimizer detects very well the chain of conditions and generate code, which at the first non null return value jumps to the end ([online proof](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZTUAHAvVAOwGdK0AbVAV2J4OmAIIcAtiADkABmmk0Exnh6YA8mwDCCAIZtgmGfICUpDgOLIj0gNT3bAUgBMAZjxtkPflieutrBwExJi6Eo6u2I6yog62/BwewLZsYZgcjLrWtkHoEQBC0bFxRaUxcR4EtgBmEOgCAEZqTs4AbOgmTgDsheVxtnmuACLoALSyAHQArAVOfXEhBIJsAxFDa5Oys0UlXevz9jsOlbYSuh4QnY49R/0Djc2D%2BXPFd8geflGRTy939ieYYjEDbbA5xBqoVA8WyoADWfiGtmC/EwoNe/ThCJh8JcrVxtgggOBw1qHRMYDAINcz1uGJxw2xLTxbQJRLWpJM5Mpwy21N%2Bf0xa0ZuPxhKB7LqnIpVJpYIcgoZgraorZJMlXJl/LeAgIES0erhs0OB2iAE5FstbLzeujrvtRNIzDwZFMFGwZLQFKgZPrnIU/TlLNkXK5PaQCMZHWZYSAprJSM7pAAWN2RhgyBRceMRuSO0hwWBIJQqNRkCgQYuqQEgYCtZykaqqAiArgQBpppQSTBsAiaHgATzT%2BBCyBYADd0mnKphE6YGMxWJwZKN1M484nXaR3bn09IQ7RbAB3QgIWwADwAHK1Rq0k7ZgMhkLZWhM1%2BHI5zSDG4wmZCmt2m3rSJmIDZh%2BToyG%2B27yLuCg5qYZgTsQiTsCASZAA%3D%3D)).

You could even envisage a consistency check at the end of the function that could during the testing phase identify mismatches between the ok flag and the error code.

```
assert( (ok==false && err!=0) || (ok==true && err==0) );
```

Mistakes such of a `==0` inadvertently replaced with a `!=0` or logical connector errors would easily be spotted during the debugging phase.

As said: I don't pretend that alternative constructs would have avoided any bug.  I just want to say that they could have made the bug more difficult to occur.

Comment: No, the Apple goto fail bug was caused by a clever programmer deciding not to include the curly braces after an if statement.  :-)  So when the next maintenance programmer (or the same one, same difference) came along and added another line of code that should have only executed when the if statement evaluated true, the statement ran every time. Bam, the "goto fail" bug, which was a *major* security bug. But it had essentially nothing to do with the fact that a goto statement was used.

Comment: @Craig your analysis is technically correct.  But I think it's too narrow sighted:  if all these `goto fails` would in first place not have been used , and if instead the block to be protected from all these potential errors would have been enclosed in an if clause with a condition excluding the errors, the vultnerability would have been avoided.  And no missing curly brace would have ever existed at this stage.

Comment: The Apple "goto fail" bug was directly caused by a line of code being duplicated. The particular effect of *that bug* was caused by that line being a `goto` inside a brace-less `if` statement. But if you're suggesting that avoiding `goto` will make your code immune to the effects of randomly duplicated lines, I have bad news for you.

Comment: @immibis it is obvious that the line is duplicated.  It is also obvious that some other line in the code show suspicious indentation.  I propose you to read careflly the faulty function, and my edit where I show how absence of goto could have lead to more compact and more robust code.

Comment: @Christophe: Not that you can't do something similar to what you suggest to eliminate goto statements, but the original code is more legible than yours to me. Also, I'm not sure your code actually works. The original code preserves the error for the fail code. Your code just preserves the fact that there was an error. Further, there's a problem in the original that "err" is never initialized. Initializing it to something specific, then checking for that value in the calling function, would have informed the testing team there was a problem because they were getting an error of "uninitialized".

Comment: @MichaelS this code is exactly equivalent to the original code and preserves the error code as well.  It takes benefit of the logical and (&&) which does evaluate the second term ONLY IF the first term is true (meaning that if one of the ok fails, the err is not evaluated and is hence left intact).  I invite you to look at the assembler generated by this code (see online demo) and compare it with the goto alternative: you'll be surprised.

Comment: You're using shortcut boolean operator behavior to execute a statement via side-effect and claiming that's more clear than an `if` statement?  Fun times.  :)

Comment: @Craig i just reused the side effects which wherre there in the original code. I just give that equivalent form as an example. You could as well transform every statement of my second snippet in a proper if block without side effects; it would be a little more verbose but wiuld still be without goto and cleaner.

Comment: If instead of "goto fail" there had been a statement "failed = true" the exact same thing would have happened.

Comment: By your reasoning, functions also cause unreadable code if there are too many of them. I think that goes for all bits of code.

Comment: @gnasher729 i propose that you honestly try the construct by rewriting the code as I suggested in my second snippet and then try to insert a line looking like you said: i think it would be easy to spot it. Furthermore in the original code you don't know when reaching fail if it is normal termination or not. With the sequential ok approach, you could insert some assertion to check consistency and prevent such nasty bugs: assert((ok==false && err!=0)||(ok==true && err==0))

Comment: That bug was caused by a sloppy developer not paying attention to what he or she was doing, and not _reading_ their own code changes. Nothing more, nothing less. Okay, maybe throw in some testing oversights in there too.

Comment: @Christophe: Good. By the way, Dijkstra didn't choose that title; the editor did. Dijkstra was more nuanced.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd guess that this was a result of a botched merge. I've seen it happen many times before :/ It's easy to make something like that slip when your merge attempt results in a few hundred conflicting files. Especially when the changes are something silly like whitespace changes that your mergetool doesn't ignore - our brains aren't well equipped to spot all the problems reading file changes line-by-line; the brain has to ignore duplicates all the time when dealing with reality. But that's really getting off-topic quickly :D The important bit is "not the fault of goto".

Comment: @Luaan: Simply review each change in a diff after a merge and before commit. Should be basic standard practice. If there are too many changes to review, the branch diverges too much and should have been sync'd to trunk more frequently.

Comment: @Christophe: Missing my point. The thread is about "goto" and the problem wasn't caused by the use of goto.

Comment: the lack of `goto` in java just makes developers do stupid things like use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: @MatthewWhited It appears that Java's `goto` (`break label`) is [even more confusing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/886979/819417).

Comment: The bug was released to production due to insufficient testing. IMO every function containing a branch of any kind requires at least one unit test. Bugs are most often found in code that wasn't tested.

Comment: @gnasher729   Let's look at the "science" in "computer science" and forget the emotions.  The only **observable and objective fact** here is that the wrong behavior of the software is caused by a goto statement.  That it should have been properly aligned, included in curly braces,  caused by copy/pasting or that the developer was sloppy are only **subjective interpretations** of the facts.  Furthermore, the `fail`label can be reached via one of the 13 error processing gotos AND via normal control flow in case everything is fine: this doesn't allow for additional consistency checks.

Comment: @Luaan The hypotheses of a botched merge is very interesting.  It would indeed explain also the strange misalignment in other places of that function.

Comment: So, to sum this answer up: `goto` doesn't break things in and of itself, although it does make it more likely that the programmer will unintentionally break something.  If something _does_ break, though, `goto` makes it break _worse_.

Comment: @Christophe: The bug was caused by a statement getting executed unconditionally, because an identical line where the statement was executed conditionally was duplicated by mistake. The fact that the duplicated statement was a "goto" statement is completely irrelevant to the bug. But if you want to keep your emotions in check, that's fine with me.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the designers of Ada did not allow unbracketed control structures, PRECISELY to prevent this kind of error.

Comment: "The risk of making wrong/unfounded assumptions is hence quite big." Please turn that sentence into a heading near the top and elaborate on it. That is the *core* of your answer, but it takes 5 bullet points and an introductory sentence to get to it.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am going to have to agree with you. This historical example  while interesting, has little to do with `goto`, because any statement there would have caused an issue. Why some projects allow and even encourages  unbracketted conditional statements blows my mind.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: Much as some people love to bash BASIC, I like the vb.net approach of having two forms of `If..Then`--one where all consequent statements are on the same line separated by colons, and one where no statements follow `Then` on the same line, but a later line includes a balancing `End If` line [there may also be an intervening `Else` line].  In most cases, the longer form makes sense, but if there are a bunch of statements like  `If X<0 Then X=0`, `If X>5 Then X=5`, etc. putting each condition+consequence on one line may be nicer than spreading each combo over three lines.

Comment: @gnasher729 If, instead of `goto fail;`, there had been the line `fail(err);`, it still would have had the same effect!

Comment: An accidentally missing `&&` in your alternative suggestion would, I think, have a similar effect. The faulty code is actually one of the places where you can make a reasonable argument to use goto. (Namely jump to cleanup code from several places where an error makes continuing impossible.)

Comment: Regarding the SSL bug example: Yes, a clever compiler could warn about inconsistent indentation. But even simpler, it could warn about the fact that some code (the `if (...)` above) is unreachable (and probably skipped entirely instead of being translated by the compiler).

Comment: Ignoring the Apple example, I think `return` should be added to your list of useful Java keywords. Breaking code into a function and calling that function is *often* (but decidedly *not* always) cleaner than having large sets of flow controls with different purposes inside a single function.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider indeed you are right. However I think that the misalignment would be verry visible. Furthermore, it is easy to add a consisteny check at the end of the chain to assert that ok and err==0 are either both set or both clear

Comment: @Christophe "The only observable and objective fact here is that the wrong behavior of the software is caused by a goto statement." - if the wrong behaviour had been caused by a function call statement would you still say "The only **observable and objective fact here** is that the wrong behaviour of the software is caused by a function call statement" and then recommend avoiding function call statements? (Yes I know function calls are pedantically not statements in C)

Comment: @Christophe: The observable and objective fact is that the behavior triggered by the `goto fail` statement *was happening at the wrong time*. Why was it happening at the wrong time? Because there were two statements after an `if`, with no curly braces. If both `goto` statements had been in curly braces, the code would have performed properly. The bug isn't the fault of `goto`.

Comment: Personally, I love seeing curly braces, even for a single statement, because I know they reduce bugs. They help ensure code correctness (code that does the right thing). Now there's science over emotion (and aesthetics) for you.  ;-) Although, I suppose the warm fuzzy feeling I get when I see the braces probably does have some emotional component.

Comment: *"With a `goto` statement, you break that straightforward flow, and break the expectations. For example, you might not notice that you have still to free the resources."* A similar issue occurs with exceptions, except that their `throw` statement is typically hidden inside functions. In fact, any jump statement has this issue. To me, the important part is: *"And as many places can send you to a single goto target, it's also not obvious to know for sure the state you are in when reaching this place."* -- there's no obvious connection between the label and the previously executed statement.

Comment: @dyp you could also mention setjmp/logjmp here, as this can easily cause unstability and leaking for the reasons that you very well explain. However for exceptions, despite the break in control flow, you are in a safer situation: first if RAII was used the stack unwinding ensures proper cleaning; then when you reach the catch block you know for sure the kind of relevant exception that ocurred. There is no risk of confusion between normal flow and error handling flow there: you never execute the catch block by accident.

Comment: @Craig i fully agree with you on the braces. 30 years ago, in my early days as developer, and with the debugging technology from then,I once spent a big part of a winter night to find out that i added a semicolumn at the end of a while. The curly brace reflex would have avoided the mess. But this is another discussion ;-)

Comment: +1 _"...in 10 years of C, I used maximum 10 gotos..."_ Great, 1 goto per year.

Answer (score 35):

The famous Dijkstra article was written at a time when some programming languages were actually capable of creating **subroutines having multiple entry and exit points.**  In other words, you could literally jump into the middle of a function, and jump out at any place within the function, without actually calling that function or returning from it in the conventional way.  That's still true of assembly language.  Nobody ever argues that such an approach is superior to the structured method of writing software that we now use.

In most modern programming languages, functions are very specifically defined with **one entry and one exit point.**  The entry point is where you specify the parameters to the function and call it, and the exit point is where you return the resulting value and continue execution at the instruction following the original function call.

Within that function, you ought to be able to do whatever you wish, within reason.  If putting a goto or two in the function makes it clearer or improves your speed, why not?  The whole point of a function is to sequester a bit of clearly-defined functionality, so that you don't have to think about how it works internally anymore.  Once it's written, you just use it.

And yes, you can have multiple return statements inside a function; there's still always one place in a proper function from which you return (the back side of the function, basically).  That's not at all the same thing as jumping out of a function with a goto before it has a chance to properly return.

[image]

So it's not really about using goto's.  It's about avoiding their abuse.  Everyone agrees that you can make a terribly convoluted program using gotos, but you can do the same by abusing functions as well (it's just a lot easier to abuse gotos).

For what it's worth, ever since I graduated from line-number-style BASIC programs to structured programming using Pascal and curly-brace languages, I've never had to use a goto.  The only time I've been tempted to use one is to do an early exit from a nested loop (in languages that don't support multi-level early exit from loops), but I can usually find another way that is cleaner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47529/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-harvey-what-kind-of-bugs-do-goto-statements-lea).

Answer (score 12):

When the [wigwam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigwam) was current architectural art, their builders could undoubtedly give you sound practical advice regarding construction of wigwams, how to let smoke escape, and so on. Fortunately, today's builders can probably forget most of that advice.

When the [stagecoach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagecoach) was current transportational art, their drivers could undoubtedly give you sound practical advice regarding horses of stagecoaches, how to defend against [highwaymen,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highwayman) and so on. Fortunately, today's motorists can forget most of that advice, too.

When [punched cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card) were current programming art, their practitioners could likewise give you sound practical advice regarding organization of cards, how to number statements, and so on. I am not sure that that advice is very relevant today.

Are you old enough even to know the phrase ["to number statements"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_number#Line_numbers_and_GOTOs)? You don't need to know it, but if you don't, then you aren't familiar with the historical context in which the warning against `goto` was principally relevant.

The warning against `goto` is just not very relevant today. With basic training in while/for loops and function calls, you won't even *think* to issue a `goto` very often. When you do think of it, you probably have a reason, so go ahead.

But can the `goto` statement not be abused?

Answer: sure, it can be abused, but its abuse is a pretty tiny problem in software engineering compared to far, far more common mistakes such as using a variable where a constant will serve, or such as cut-and-paste programming (otherwise known as neglect to refactor). I doubt that you're in much danger. Unless you are using `longjmp` or otherwise transferring control to faraway code, if you think to use a `goto` or you would just like to try it for fun, go ahead. You'll be fine.

You may notice the lack of *recent* horror stories in which `goto` plays the villain.  Most or all of these stories seem to be 30 or 40 years old.  You stand on solid ground if you regard those stories as mostly obsolete.

Comment: I see that I've attracted at least one downvote. Well, that's to be expected. More downvotes may come. I'm not going to give the conventional answer, though, when decades of programming experience have taught me that, in this instance, the conventional answer happens to be *wrong.* This is my view, at any rate. I have given my reasons. The reader can decide.

Comment: Your post is good too bad I can't downvote comments.

Comment: Maybe, the general takeaway is: if you ever get an advice, you should also be told about the context in which the advice was developed. Be careful about an advice whose original context you don’t know.

Answer (score 11):

> ## What kind of bugs do “goto” statements lead to? Are there any historically significant examples?

I used to use `goto` statements when writing BASIC programs as a child as a simple way to get for and while loops (Commodore 64 BASIC didn't have while-loops, and I was too immature to learn the proper syntax and usage of for-loops).
My code was frequently trivial, but any loop bugs could be immediately attributed to my usage of goto.

I now use primarily Python,
a high level programming language that has determined it has no need for goto.

When Edsger Dijkstra declared "Goto considered harmful" in 1968 he did not give a handful of examples where related bugs could be blamed on the goto, rather, he declared that `goto` was [unnecessary for higher level languages](http://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Estorm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf) and that it should be avoided in favor of what we consider normal control flow today: loops and conditionals. His words:

> The unbridled use of the **go to** has an immediate consequence that it becomes terribly hard to find a meaningful set of coordinates in which to describe the process progress.
> [...]
> The **go to** statement as it stands is just too primitive; it is too much an invitation to make a mess of one's program.

He probably had mountains of examples of bugs from every time he debugged code with `goto` in it. But his paper was a generalized position statement backed up by proof that `goto` was unnecessary for higher level languages. The generalized bug is that you may have no ability to statically analyze the code under question.

Code is much harder to statically analyze with `goto` statements, especially if you jump back in your control flow (which I used to do) or to some unrelated section of code. Code can and was written this way. It was done to highly optimize for very scarce computing resources and thus the architectures of the machines.

### An Apocryphal Example

There was a blackjack program that a maintainer found to be quite elegantly optimized but also [impossible for him to "fix"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html) due to the nature of the code. It was programmed in machine code which is heavily reliant on gotos - so I think this story quite relevant. This is the best canonical example I can think of.

### A Counter-Example

However, the C source of CPython (the most common and reference Python implementation) uses `goto` statements to great effect. They are used to bypass irrelevant control flow inside functions to get to the end of functions, making the functions more efficient without losing readability. This respects one of the ideals of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) - to have a single exit point for functions.

For the record, I find this counter-example to be quite easy to statically analyze.

Comment: The "Story of Mel" I've encountered was on a strange architecture where (1) every machine language instruction does a goto after its operation, and (2) it was terribly inefficient to place a sequence of instructions in consecutive memory locations. And the program was written in hand-optimized assembly, not a compiled language.

Comment: @MilesRout I think you could be correct here, but the wikipedia page on structured programming says: "The most common deviation, found in many languages, is the use of a return statement for early exit from a subroutine. This results in multiple exit points, instead of the single exit point required by structured programming." - you're saying this is incorrect? Do you have a source to cite?

Comment: @AaronHall That's not the original meaning.

Answer (score 7):

To add one thing to the other excellent answers, with `goto` statements it can be difficult to tell exactly how you got to any given place in the program. You can know that an exception occurred at some specific line but if there are `goto`'s in the code there is no way to tell what statements executed to result in this exception causing state without searching the whole program. There is no call stack and no visual flow. It is possible that there is a statement 1000 lines away which put you in a bad state executed a `goto` to the line which raised an exception.

Comment: Visual Basic 6 and VBA have painful error handling, but if you use `On Error Goto errh`, you can use `Resume` to retry, `Resume Next` to skip the offending line, and `Erl` to know which line it was (if you use line numbers).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I've done very little with Visual Basic, I did not know that. I will add a comment about it.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman on further thought, isn't think something different than figuring out how you ended up at the line that caused the error?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: The VB6 semantics of "resume" are horrible if an error occurs within a subroutine that doesn't have its own on-error block.  `Resume` will re-execute that function from the start, and `Resume Next` will skip everything in the function that hasn't yet.

Comment: @supercat Like i said, it's painful. If you need to know the exact line, you should number them all, or temporarily disable the error handling with [`On Error Goto 0`](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-on-error-statement/) and manually Debug. `Resume` is meant to be used after checking `Err.Number` and making the necessary adjustments.

Comment: I should note that in a modern language, `goto` only works with labeled lines, which appears to have been superseded by [labeled loops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751229/819417).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: The issue isn't merely knowing where the error occurred (which is problematic in vb unless one numbers every line where an error occurred) but the fact that errors anywhere within a called function are treated as errors at the call site.

Comment: @supercat That's how it's supposed to work, otherwise you get [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194626/in-java-how-to-force-an-exception-to-bubble-up)

Comment: This problem can be avoided by using the `comefrom` statement instead of `goto` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

goto is harder for humans to reason about than other forms of flow control.

Programming correct code is hard.  Writing correct programs is hard, determining if programs are correct is hard, proving programs correct is hard.

Getting code to vaguely do what you want is easy compared to everything else about programming.

goto solves some programs with getting code to do what you want.  It does not help make checking for correctness easier, while its alternatives often do.

There are styles of programming where goto is the appropriate solution.  There are even styles of programming where its evil twin, comefrom, is the appropriate solution.  In both of these cases, extreme care has to be done to ensure you are using it in an understood pattern, and lots of manual checking that you aren't doing something difficult to ensure correctness with it.

As an example, there is a feature of some languages called coroutines.  Coroutines are threadless threads; execution state without a thread to run it on.  You can ask them to execute, and they can run part of themselves and then suspend themselves, handing back flow control.

"Shallow" coroutines in languages without coroutine support (like C++ pre-C++20 and C) are possible using a mixture of gotos and manual state management.  "Deep" coroutines can be done using the `setjmp` and `longjmp` functions of C.

There are cases where coroutines are so useful that writing them manually and carefully is worth it.

In the case of C++, they are being found useful enough that they are extending the language to support them.  The `goto`s and manual state management is being hidden behind a zero cost abstraction layer, permitting programmers to write them *without* the difficulty of having to prove their mess of goto, `void**`s, manual construction/destruction of state, etc is correct.

The goto gets hidden behind a higher level abstraction, like `while` or `for` or `if` or `switch`.  Those higher level abstractions are easier to prove correct and check.

If the language was *missing* some of them (like some modern languages are missing coroutines), either limpling along with a pattern that doesn't fit the problem, or using goto, becomes your alternatives.

Getting a computer to vaguely do what you want it to do in common cases is *easy*.  Writing reliably robust code is *hard*.  Goto helps the first far more than it helps the second; hence "goto considered harmful", as it is a sign of superficially "working" code with deep and hard to track down bugs.  With sufficient effort you can still make code with "goto" reliably robust, so holding the rule of as absolute is wrong; but as a rule of thumb, it is a good one.

Comment: `longjmp` is only legal in C for unwinding the stack back to a `setjmp` in a parent function.  (Like breaking out of multiple levels of nesting, but for function calls instead of loops).  `longjjmp` to a context from a `setjmp` done in a function that has since returned is not legal (and I suspect won't work in practice in most cases).  I'm not familiar with co-routines, but from your description of a co-routine as similar to a user-space thread, I think it would need its own stack as well as a saved-register context, and `longjmp` only gives you register-saving, not a separate stack.

Comment: Oh, I should have just googled: http://fanf.livejournal.com/105413.html describes making stack space for the coroutine to run.  (Which as I suspected, is necessary on top of just using setjmp/longjmp).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Implementations are not required to provide any means by which code could create a pair jmp_buff that is suitable for use as a coroutine.  Some implementations do specify a means via which code may create one even though the Standard doesn't require them to provide such an ability.  I would not describe code which relies upon such techniques as "standard C", since in many cases a jmp_buff will be an opaque structure that is not guaranteed to behave consistently between different compilers.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this code, from http://www-personal.umich.edu/~axe/research/Software/CC/CC2/TourExec1.1.f.html that was actually part of a large Prisoner's Dilemma simulation. If you've seen old FORTRAN or BASIC code, you'll realize it's not that unusual.

```fortran
C  Not nice rules in second round of tour (cut and pasted 7/15/93)
   FUNCTION K75R(J,M,K,L,R,JA)
C  BY P D HARRINGTON
C  TYPED BY JM 3/20/79
   DIMENSION HIST(4,2),ROW(4),COL(2),ID(2)
   K75R=JA       ! Added 7/32/93 to report own old value
   IF (M .EQ. 2) GOTO 25
   IF (M .GT. 1) GOTO 10
   DO 5 IA = 1,4
     DO 5 IB = 1,2
5  HIST(IA,IB) = 0

   IBURN = 0
   ID(1) = 0
   ID(2) = 0
   IDEF = 0
   ITWIN = 0
   ISTRNG = 0
   ICOOP = 0
   ITRY = 0
   IRDCHK = 0
   IRAND = 0
   IPARTY = 1
   IND = 0
   MY = 0
   INDEF = 5
   IOPP = 0
   PROB = .2
   K75R = 0
   RETURN

10 IF (IRAND .EQ. 1) GOTO 70
   IOPP = IOPP + J
   HIST(IND,J+1) = HIST(IND,J+1) + 1
   IF (M .EQ. 15 .OR. MOD(M,15) .NE. 0 .OR. IRAND .EQ. 2) GOTO 25
   IF (HIST(1,1) / (M - 2) .GE. .8) GOTO 25
   IF (IOPP * 4 .LT. M - 2 .OR. IOPP * 4 .GT. 3 * M - 6) GOTO 25
   DO 12 IA = 1,4
12 ROW(IA) = HIST(IA,1) + HIST(IA,2)

   DO 14 IB = 1,2
     SUM = .0
     DO 13 IA = 1,4
13   SUM = SUM + HIST(IA,IB)
14 COL(IB) = SUM

   SUM = .0
   DO 16 IA = 1,4
     DO 16 IB = 1,2
       EX = ROW(IA) * COL(IB) / (M - 2)
       IF (EX .LE. 1.) GOTO 16
       SUM = SUM + ((HIST(IA,IB) - EX) ** 2) / EX
16 CONTINUE

   IF (SUM .GT. 3) GOTO 25
   IRAND = 1
   K75R = 1
   RETURN

25 IF (ITRY .EQ. 1 .AND. J .EQ. 1) IBURN = 1
   IF (M .LE. 37 .AND. J .EQ. 0) ITWIN = ITWIN + 1
   IF (M .EQ. 38 .AND. J .EQ. 1) ITWIN = ITWIN + 1
   IF (M .GE. 39 .AND. ITWIN .EQ. 37 .AND. J .EQ. 1) ITWIN = 0
   IF (ITWIN .EQ. 37) GOTO 80
   IDEF = IDEF * J + J
   IF (IDEF .GE. 20) GOTO 90
   IPARTY = 3 - IPARTY
   ID(IPARTY) = ID(IPARTY) * J + J
   IF (ID(IPARTY) .GE. INDEF) GOTO 78
   IF (ICOOP .GE. 1) GOTO 80
   IF (M .LT. 37 .OR. IBURN .EQ. 1) GOTO 34
   IF (M .EQ. 37) GOTO 32
   IF (R .GT. PROB) GOTO 34
32 ITRY = 2
   ICOOP = 2
   PROB = PROB + .05
   GOTO 92

34 IF (J .EQ. 0) GOTO 80
   GOTO 90

70 IRDCHK = IRDCHK + J * 4 - 3
   IF (IRDCHK .GE. 11) GOTO 75
   K75R = 1
   RETURN

75 IRAND = 2
   ICOOP = 2
   K75R = 0
   RETURN

78 ID(IPARTY) = 0
   ISTRNG = ISTRNG + 1
   IF (ISTRNG .EQ. 8) INDEF = 3
80 K75R = 0
   ITRY = ITRY - 1
   ICOOP = ICOOP - 1
   GOTO 95

90 ID(IPARTY) = ID(IPARTY) + 1
92 K75R = 1
95 IND = 2 * MY + J + 1
   MY = K75R
   RETURN
   END
```

There's a lot of issues here that go well beyond the GOTO statement here; I honestly think the GOTO statement was a bit of a scapegoat. But the control flow is absolutely not clear here, and code is mixed together in ways that make it very unclear what's going on. Even without adding comments or using better variable names, changing this to a block structure without GOTOs would make it much easier to read and follow.

Comment: so true :-)  May be worth to mention: legacy FORTAN and BASIC didn't have block structures, so that if a THEN clause could not hold on one line GOTO was the only alternative.

Comment: Text labels instead of numbers, or at least comments on the numbered lines, would help a lot.

Comment: Back in my FORTRAN-IV days: I restricted my use of GOTO to implement IF/ELSE IF / ELSE blocks, WHILE loops and BREAK and NEXT in loops. Someone showed me the evils of spaghetti code and why you should structure to avoid it even if you have to implement your block structures with GOTO. Later I started using a pre-processor (RATFOR, IIRC). Goto is not intrinsically evil, it's just an over-powerful low-level construct that maps to an assembler branch instruction. If you have to use it because your language is deficient, use it to build or augment the proper block structures.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: That is garden-variety FORTRAN IV code.  Text labels were not supported in FORTRAN IV.  I do not know whether the more recent versions of the language support them.  Comments on the same line as code were not supported in standard FORTRAN IV, although there may have been vendor-specific extensions to support them.  I do not know what the "current" FORTRAN standard says: I abandoned FORTRAN a long time ago, and I do not miss it.  (The most recent FORTRAN code I've seen bears a strong resemblance to early-1970s PASCAL.)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm That would be too much to hope for as it doesn't even do proper IF blocks, but `! Added 7/32/93 to report own old value` looks like a comment to me.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: Vendor-specific extension.  The code in general is REALLY shy on comments.  Also, there's a convention that became common some places, of putting line numbers only on CONTINUE and FORMAT statements, to make it easier to add lines later.  This code doesn't follow that convention.

Comment: [You may also encounter Fortran programs that use the exclamation mark (!) for comments. This is not a standard part of Fortran 77, but is supported by several Fortran 77 compilers and is explicitly allowed in Fortran 90.](http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/03_basics.html)

Comment: A lot of the GOTO-madness in this code is caused by the fact that there is no IF / ELSE / ENDIF in FORTRAN IV. Take Label 25. In C, I would replace it with "if (sum <= 3) { irand = 1; k57r = 1; return; }, one GOTO and one label gone in five seconds. It doesn't help that loops need labels.

Comment: The original work was from the early eighties, so the ! comment seem to have been added a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of maintainable programming is *encapsulation*.  The point is that you interface with a module/routine/subroutine/component/object by using a defined interface, and only that interface, and the results will be predictable (assuming that the unit was effectively tested).

Within a single unit of code, the same principle applies.  If you consistently apply structured programming or object-oriented programming principles, you will not:

1. create unexpected paths through the code
2. arrive in sections of code with undefined or impermissible variable values
3. exit a path of the code with undefined or impermissible variable values
4. fail to complete a transaction unit
5. leave portions of code or data in memory that are effectively dead, but ineligible for garbage cleanup and reallocation, because you have not signalled their release using an explicit construct that invokes releasing them as the code control path exits the unit

Some of the more common symptoms of these processing errors include memory leaks, memory hoarding, pointer overflows, crashes, incomplete data records, record add / chg / delete exceptions, memory page faults, and so on.

The user-observable manifestations of these problems include user interface lock-up, gradually decreasing performance, incomplete data records, inability to initiate or complete transactions, corrupted data, network outages, power outages, embedded systems failures (from the loss of control of missiles to the loss of tracking and control ability in air traffic control systems), timer failures, and so on and so on. The catalog is *very* extensive.

Comment: You answered without mentioning `goto` even once. :)

Answer (score 0):

**goto** is dangerous because it is usually used where not needed. Using anything that is not needed is dangerous, but **goto** especially. If you google you will find lots of errors around caused by goto, this is not per-se a reason to not using it (bugs always happens when you use language features because that's intrinsic in programming), but some of them are clearly highly related to **goto** usage.

---

Reasons to use/not use **goto**:

- If you need a loop, you have to use `while` or `for`.
- If you need to do conditional jump, use `if/then/else`
- If you need procedure, call a function/method.
- If you need to quit a function, just `return`.

I can count on my fingers places where I've seen `goto` used and used properly.

- CPython
- libKTX
- probably few more

In libKTX there is a function that has the following code

```cpp
if(something)
    goto cleanup;

if(bla)
    goto cleanup;

cleanup:
    delete [] array;
```

Now in this place `goto` is usefull because the language is C:

- we are inside a function
- we cannot write a cleanup function (because we enter another scope, and making accessible caller function state is more burden)

This use case is usefull because in C we do not have classes, so the simplest way to cleanup is using a `goto`.

If we had the same code in C++ there's no need for goto anymore:

```cpp
class MyClass{
    public:

    void Function(){
        if(something)
            return Cleanup(); // invalid syntax in C#, but valid in C++
        if(bla)
            return Cleanup(); // invalid syntax in C#, but valid in C++
    }

    // access same members, no need to pass state (compiler do it for us).
    void Cleanup(){

    }



}
```

---

**What kind of bugs it can lead to?** Anything. Infinite loops, wrong order of execution, stack screw..

***A documented case*** is a vulnerability in SSL that allowed Man in the middle attacks caused by wrong use of goto: [here's the article](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/)

That's a typo error, but went unnoticed for a while, if the code were structured in an other way, tested properly such error could have not been possible.

Comment: There's lots of comments to one answer that explain very clearly that the use of "goto" was totally irrelevent to the SSL bug - the bug was caused by careless duplication of one line of code, so it was once executed conditionally, and once unconditionally.

Comment: Yeah I'm waiting for a better historical example of a goto bug before I accept. As said; It really wouldn't matter what was on that line of code; The lack of curly braces would have executed it and caused an error regardless.  I am curious though; what is a "Stack Screw"?

Comment: An example from code I worked on previously in PL/1 CICS. Program put out a screen consisting of single line maps. When the screen was returned it found the array of maps it had sent. Used the elements of that to find the index in one array, and then used that index to an index of array variables to do a GOTO to so it could process that individual map. If the array of maps sent was incorrect (or had been corrupted) then it could try to do a GOTO to the wrong label, or worse crash because it accessed an element after the end of the array of label variables. Rewritten to use case type syntax.